# dot product over a basis

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, change-of-basis

If $u$ and $v$ are any two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is any base for $\mathbb{R}^n$, then is it true or false that

$[u \cdot v]_{\mathcal{B}}=[u ]_{\mathcal{B}} \cdot [v ]_{\mathcal{B}}$  ?

I believe it is true right, because dot product preserves the angles between the vectors, right?

Comment: What is $[u\cdot v]_{\mathcal B}$?

Comment: it is the value of the dot product written with respect to the base $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: But $u\cdot v$ is just a real number. What do you mean when you talk about writing a real number with respect to the base $\mathcal B$?

Comment: it is question in my homework to determine if the statement true or false. I assume that the statement asks if the dot product value changes as we change the bases.

Answer (score 1):

We can see
$u\cdot v$
as the product $u\cdot v=u^{\top}v$ if we consider the matrices of the components of vectors as columns: $u=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u^1\\
\vdots\\
u^n
\end{array}
\right)$
and similarly for $v$.

But it is known that under a change of basis the new components of a vector $u$ will be $B^{-1}u$ where $B$ is the matrix of that change, which is not
singular to asure the linear independence of the new basis.

So
\begin{eqnarray*}
u\cdot v&=&u^{\top}v,\\
&=&(BB^{-1}u)^{\top}(BB^{-1}v),\\
&=&(B^{-1}u)^{\top}\ (B^{\top}B)\ B^{-1}v.
\end{eqnarray*}
and it is here that we can see how the matrix $B^{\top}B$ is "pairing" the new versions of both $u$ and $v$ without altering the number
$u\cdot v$.

Comment: the connection with your notations is $[u]_{\mathcal B}=B^{-1}u$